# SOA Service Boundary and production support

Tags: rest, soa

Our development group is working towards building up with service catalog.

Right now, we have two groups, one to sale a product, another to service that product.
We have one particular service that calculates if the price of the product is profitable. When a sale occurs, the sale can be overridden by a manager. This sale must also be represented in another system to track various sales and the numbers must match. The parameters of profitability also change, and are different from month to month, but a sale may be based on the previous set of parameters.

Right now the sale profitability service only calculates the profit, it also provides a RESTful URI.

One group of developers has suggested that the profitability service also support these "manager overrides" and support a date parameter to calculate based on a previous date. Of course the sales group of developers disagree. If the service won't support this, the servicing developers will have to do an ETL between two systems for each product(s), instead of just the profitability service. Right now since we do not have a set of services to handle this, production support gets the request and then has to update the 1+ systems associated for that given product.

So, if a service works for a narrow slice, but an exception based business process breaks it, does that mean the boundaries of the service are incorrect and need to account for the change in business process?

Two, does adding a date parameter extend the boundary of the service too much, or should it be excepted that if the service already has the parameters, it would also have a history of parameters as well? At this moment, we don't not have a service that only stores the parameters as no one has required a need for it.

If there is any clarification needed before an answer can be given, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key here is: How much pain would be incurred by both teams if and ETL was introduced between to the two?

Not that I think you're over-analysing this, but if I may, you probably have an opinion that adding a date parameter into the service contract is bad, but also dislike the idea of the ETL.

Well, strategy aside, I find these days my overriding instinct is to focus less on the technical ins and outs and more on the purely practical.

At the end of the day, ETL is simple, reliable, and relatively pain free to implement, however it comes with side effects. The main one is that you'll be coupling changes to your service's db schema with an outside party, which will limit options to evolve your service in the future.

On the other hand allowing consumer demand to dictate service evolution is easy and low-friction, but also a rocky road as you may become beholden to that consumer at the expense of others.

Another possibility is to allow the extra service parameters to be delivered to the consumer via a [message](http://www.eaipatterns.com/MessageChannel.html), rather then across the same service. This would allow you to keep your service boundary intact and for the consumer to hold the necessary parameters local to themselves.

Apologies if this does not address your question directly.